# How to specify startDate and endDate in ETrade Transaction History

Tags: rest

The Etrade API documentation at https://content.etrade.com/etrade/estation/pdf/API_Technical_Documentation.pdf includes the following snippet for getting Deposit history for an account:

accounts/rest/xxxxxxxx/transactions/DEPOSITS?startDate=01012012&endDate=12312012&count=25

but the results are actually only for the last 30 days even though the start and end dates are specified.

Has anyone had success with this API?  How are startDate and endDate supposed to be specified?

Comment: Do you mean to be limiting the transactions returned with count=25? Perhaps you are cutting off the rest of the year's transactions?

Comment: At the moment, the query is returning 7 items (which happens to be the number of deposits for the account in question over the last 30 days), so I don't think the count=25 is truncating anything yet.  For what it's worth, substituting values of 6, 5, 4 etc. truncate the results as expected.